# toggle button controlled remotely

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle

I have a div toggling on click of a button which I have also set to toggle...I would like to allow the user to close the div by either clicking the same toggle button or by clicking a close option in the revealed div.  The problem is that the toggle button is then reversed if the user chooses to use the close option, because it is not set to toggle with the close option.

```
<!-- Toggle Button -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.addEventListener){
window.addEventListener('load',multiImageSwap,false);
 }
else { 
if(window.attachEvent){
   window.attachEvent('onload',multiImageSwap);
  }
 }

function multiImageSwap(){
   test=true;
document.getElementById('pic').onmouseover=function() {
if(test==true) {
   this.src='images/SN_Page_10_23_Possible_19A.png';
 }
else {
   this.src='images/SN_Page_10_23_Possible_19B.png';
  }
 }
document.getElementById('pic').onmouseout=function() {
if(test==true) {
   this.src='images/SN_Page_10_23_Possible_19A.png';
 }
else {
   this.src='images/SN_Page_10_23_Possible_19B.png';
  }
 }
document.getElementById('pic').onclick=function() {
if(test==true) {
   this.src='images/SN_Page_10_23_Possible_19B.png';
   test=false;
 }
else {
   this.src='images/SN_Page_10_23_Possible_19A.png';
   test=true;
   }
  }
 }
</script>

<!-- Toggle Reading -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
</script>
```

[jsfiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/DKdontKNO/uBvgm/8/)

Comment: It appears to be working fine to me.

Comment: no problems here. Maybe because you have isolated this code from the rest, the error you are having is in that part of your code?